# How to sync SQLite on Android to MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite, xampp

I'm trying to sync `SQLite` on Android to `MySQL` using `XAMPP`. I follow this [tutorial](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-sync-sqlite-on-android-to-mysql-db/) , however get stuck on  **Build PHP Classes**.

> Create following PHP Classes and place them under
>   ‘www/sqlitemysqlsync’ folder

How should I create PHP Classes ? Using notepad ? and where should the ‘www/sqlitemysqlsync’ folder located ?

Comment: Follw these link...it might be helpful for you..http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha I know how to create `SQLite`. But not sure how to sync `SQLite` on Android to `MySQL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to type anything as you can download the whole tutorial.

The "www/sqlitemysqlsync" folder should be placed on your localhost in the directory which your webserver allows to be used for web applications.

For example in: /var/www/html/sqlitemysqlsync

After that you probably need to configure the new web application.

For example if you are using Apache2 as your webserver you need to make (copy) a config file, change some values inside and then enable your web application.

For example:

filename: sqlitemysqlsync.conf

with the following content:

-------- begin content -----------

```
ServerName sqlitemysqlsync

ServerAlias sqlitemysqlsync

ServerAdmin webmaster@sqlitemysqlsync

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sqlitemysqlsync

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

--------- end content -----------

This file should be saved in the directory:

/etc/apache2/sites-available

Next, add your web application to the file hosts in directory /etc.

Append the following line:
127.0.0.1    sqlitemysqlsync

And save this file.

To enable your new site (the PHP application) use the command:

a2ensite sqlitemysqlsync.conf

and restart your Apache2 web server:

service apache2 restart

Everything should be fine now on the server side.